# How much space on disk do software comments take compared to the rest of the project?

Tags: language-agnostic, comments, diskspace

A question on The Workplace mentioned a company that explicitly banned code comments: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/140843/my-current-job-follows-worst-practices-how-can-i-talk-about-my-experience-in with the explanation being:

> my PM says it's not worth the disk space.

This made me really curious: disk space right now is cheap, on the order of pennies per gigabyte. Would you really save all that much money on disk space if you completely removed all comments from your code?

Comment: Note: I'm not 100% sure if this is the right stack or whether it might fit better on the Software Engineering stack. If this isn't the right place, mods feel free to move it.

Comment: If the project is one big comment then it'll take 100% of the disk space. Removing it would save 100% of the disk space --- and nuke the project.

Comment: Unless you are programming embedded computers, where weight is critical, the cost of storage is irrelevant - remnants of [xtreme programming](https://medium.com/extreme-programming/on-comments-e2b2e725cc67) that treated comments as bugs might be what motivates this restriction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In view in the wide variety of circumstance in which coding is done, I suppose that the cost of a byte of storage space must vary quite a bit. There is, however, no doubt that it must be extremely low for something like comments. On the other hand, the cost of uncommented code is *huge*: it is bug-prone, a nightmare to understand and nearly impossible to maintain.

Anyway, I Googled "cost of disk storage" and got $0.025 per GB for a 4 TB Seagate ST4000DM005...